# How can you call programs from a stored procedure?

Tags: db2, db2-400

I have followed other examples on stack exchange to call a built-in program from a stored procedure, but continue to get an error.

Working off this example ([Looking for a working example of any OS/400 API wrapped in an external SQL stored procedure wrapped in a user defined SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681270/looking-for-a-working-example-of-any-os-400-api-wrapped-in-an-external-sql-store)) I built the following to attempt to create a wrapper command to allow me to change object security (my issue is that objects I create, regardless of library) are not always accessible to others in my some function, I must manually set to a common security group.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XX.TST( IN XOBJ CHAR(32), IN XOBJTYPE CHAR(10), IN XNEWOWN CHAR(10))

LANGUAGE CL

SPECIFIC XX.TST

NOT DETERMINISTIC

NO SQL

CALLED ON NULL INPUT

EXTERNAL NAME 'QSYS/CHGOBJOWN'

PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL;

CALL XX . TST('XX/TBL1','*FILE','GRPFRIENDS');
```

I get the following error:

> External program CHGOBJOWN in QSYS not found

But have confirmed that going to the CL of the terminal emulator and typing QSYS/CHGOBJOWN takes me into the parameter input screen

Comment: Did you eliminate all the suggestions for SQL0444 in your Db2-for-i documentation?

Comment: This is because CHGOBJOWN is not a program (*PGM), but a command (*CMD).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to define a command as a program, and that just won't work. A command object (*CMD) and a program object (*PGM) are two different things, and cannot be invoked the same way. All is not lost though. There is a DB2 service that allows you to execute commands. You just have to build the proper command string.

Instead of defining a stored procedure, you can call the existing DB2 service like this:

```
call qsys2.qcmdexec('CHGOBJOWN OBJ(XX/TBL1) OBJTYPE(*FILE) NEWOWN(GRPFRIENDS)');
```

There are a whole list of services. Documentation can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzajq/rzajqservicessys.htm).

Comment: Thank you! I'm an end user so my fumbling knowledge of DB2 isn't quite enough to pick up on these things. This command is very helpful since I can now embed in an SP!

Comment: That's an IBM i thing vs. a DB2 thing, but in any case, glad I could be of assistance.